# In iOS how to use NS_ENUM?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that such questions are asked before. I looked on the net find examples but I can not figure out how to use `NS_ENUM` in my code. 
I have a list of error codes. To manage them I want to use `NS_ENUM`. I create a class which contains all my public const for the application. I want to define my enum here and use it everywhere in the app.

My code in .h file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, wsErrEnum);
```

In my .m file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, wsErrEnum) {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT = 1
};
```

I thought that I can check in the following manner:

```
if(result.ErrCode == wsErrEnum.ERR_NONE) {
// do stuff ...
}
```

, but `ERR_NONE` is not visible as property.

So my question is how to define and use `NS_ENUM` in this case.

**EDIT:**

Using

```
if(result.ErrCode == ERR_NONE) {
            NSLog(@"It is OK!");
        }
```

give me error that `ERR_NONE` is `undefined`.

**EDIT 2:**

I understand the problem. I declare `NS_ENUM` in my `.h` file (as some comments and answers suggest) and the error disappears. I try this before but in that case I did not use enum properly - I use is as `wsErrEnum.ERR_NONE`. 10x for help.

P.S. My class is `#imported` in the .m file where I try to make this comparison.

Comment: Try using result.ErrCode == ERR_NONE

Comment: @CarouselMin, I receive error that `ERR_NONE` is undeclared

Comment: Why shouldn't you declare the whole enum in the .h?

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi, 10x this really helps. I try this also at the first place but in that case I use `wsErrEnum.ERR_NONE` for comparison, which obviously did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift :

```
if result.ErrCode == wsErrEnum.ERR_NONE {
   // do stuff ...
}
```

In Objective-C :

```
if(result.ErrCode == ERR_NONE) {
   // do stuff ...
}
```

The real issue is that you have split up the declaration of `wsErrEnum`, remove it from the .m file and place the full delcaration in the .h:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, wsErrEnum) {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT = 1
};
```

But better is something like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, wsErrEnum) {
    wsErrEnumName = 0,
    wsErrEnumTimeOut = 1
};
```

---

Just a small remark, properties like your `ErrCode` should not started with a capital letter.

Comment: when I use `result.ErrCode == ERR_NONE` I receive error 
`Use of undeclared identifier 'ERR_NONE'`

Comment: Of what type is `ErrCode` ?

Comment: is `int`. I declare the enum in .h file as @DavideDeFranceschi suggested and there is no more error.

Comment: rckoenes just a reply to your remark about capital letter of `ErrCode`. I use [SudZc](http://sudzc.com) to generate SOAP service envelope - this capital letter comes from that component (and I suppose it is taken from WS)

Answer (score 2):

The only problem here is that you've declared the enum's values in your .m file.

You should declare the entire enum (values included) in your .h file.  By declaring the enum type `wsErrNum` in your .h file and the values in your .m file, you've hidden the values from all other classes.

So, in your .h file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, wsErrEnum) {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT = 1
};
```

Nothing needs to go in your .m file to declare this enum.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I use Enumerations in objective-c as `typedef enum`. Doing like this, you don't need an implementation file (.m) and the code looks like this:

```
//  Enumerations.h

@interface Enumerations

typedef enum:int {
    ERR_NONE,
    ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT
} wsErrEnum;

@end
```

By default, the compiler values the enumerations from 0 to N, in order of which they are declared. In the example above, `ERR_NONE` is `0` and `ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT` is `1`.

But you could also value the enumerations the way you preffer:

```
typedef enum:int {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT = 504
} wsErrEnum;
```

Then, you could work with `switch` and it would consider your enumeration, so it throws a warning in case you don't implement one possible result, for example:

```
switch(result.ErrCode) {
     case ERR_NONE:
     //implementation
         break;
}
```

The code above will warn you that you don't have a case implemented for `ERR_HOST_TIMEOUT`.

You can also import your `Enumerations.h` in the file `YourProjectName-Prefix.phc` so it can be used in your hole project.

```
//
//  Prefix header
//
//  The contents of this file are implicitly included at the beginning of every source file.
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    #import "Enumerations.h" //Add this line so you don't have to import your .h file every time you use it
#endif
```

Comment: With the switch to 64 bit you should really start using `NSInteger` also Apple suggest that you use the `NS_ENUM` macro.

Comment: @rckoenes in the case of `enum`, don't you think there would be no problem on using 32-bit `int` considering that my enum values wouldn't be too high?

Comment: `NSInteger` is 32 bit when compiled for 32 bit architecture and 64 bits on 64 bit architectures.

Comment: sure, but I mean, there is no need to use 64 bit even in 64 bit architectures for such small numbers like enumerations. don't you agree?

Comment: Well then there is a conversion, from 64 bit to 32 bit. I should just be good practice to use the native type.

Comment: just read this [article](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/enum-num-num/) talking about `typedef : enum`s and for me, when you need to explicit small range values to your enums you can use `typedef` instead of the macro `NS_ENUM`

Comment: i just tested and in xcode 6 there's no difference between `NS_ENUM` and `typedef` but `NS_ENUM` should compile in other environments.